# Найти пробелы между словами внутри ковычек

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не могу до конца решить вопрос с regex. Мне нужно найти пробелы в словах между ковычками (чтобы потом заменить их на подчеркивание). Как правильно написать регулярное выражение?
Пробовал (["]*\w)(\s) но это не совсем то, потому что попадают пробелы находящиеся после ковычек. Спасибо.
Пример текста, на котором тестирую (пробелы внутри ковычек):
test "test1 test2" test3
"t4 t5 test6" test7

Хочу потом получить:
test "test1_test2" test3
"t4_t5_test6" test7

Comment: Без языка программирования никак. Потому что с одной и с другой стороны у вас одинаковые разделители (`"`). Есть, конечно, один вариант, но очень неэффективный. Очень популярный, но, к сожелению, всё может повиснуть, если текст очень длинный.

Comment: Split по кавычке, Replace в чётных, Join обратно.

Comment: Да, тут придется использовать что-то вроде replace для замены пробелов. Не знаю вашей цели. Но получить фрагменты кода в кавычках можно таким выражением : ``["][0-9 \w]*["]``  ... чистый split вместо regex добавит работы

Comment: *получить фрагменты кода в кавычках* какой смысл их получать-то? конечная цель вроде чётко обозначена - заменить. А получение не даёт для её достижения ничего - более того, только создаст дополнительные проблемы в случае какого-нибудь `a a"a a"a a"a a"a a`.

Comment: Если подробнее про задачу, то есть такие строки описания полей БД:
"Location Code" character varying(10),
И есть задача поменять в названии полей пробелы на подчеркивания. Я думал это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения, но возникли сложности с ним.

Comment: Второй вариант у меня: сделать программу, которая будет расскладывать строку на символы и все их перебирать.

Comment: Кирилл, "сделать программу" можно только на языке программирования, вы каким тут пользуетесь?

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот заменяю данным образом работает все корректно.

Comment: наверно, неплохо было бы и текстом написать (прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]), что именно вы делаете.

Answer (score -1):

Ваш пример отрабатывает

```js
let str = 'test "test1 test2" test3 "t4 t5 test6" test7';
let match = str.match(/"[^"](.*?)\s+(.*?)"/g);

match.forEach(m => {
  str = str.replace(m, m.replace(/\s+/g, '_'))
});
    
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```